# Как вывести список меток на страницу категории, которые имеют общие записи?

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать?

Пример: 
Есть жанры песен - рубрики (категории)
Есть авторы песен - метки (тэги)

Требуется, например в жанре рок, вывести список авторов (метки) кто исполняет в этом жанре (рубрики).

Так же в обратную сторону, на странице автора (метки), вывести в каких жанрах он поет (рубрики).

Comment: Понятен ли мой вопрос?)

Comment: Вопрос понятен) Молчание означает, что либо не могут дать ответа, либо времени нет. Вам в Телеграм дали направление к одному из возможных вариантов решения.